# How to get Full address from lat/lng using Google Play Service ( Not use Geocoder)

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have a position at 10.792986, 106.670004. 
How to get FULL address like as :

> 207 Lê Văn Sỹ, 14, Phú Nhuận
>   Hồ Chí Minh, Vietnam

If using Geocoder, I couldn't get Full Adress.

```
List<Address> addresses = null;
        String addressText="";

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So, is there any way to use Gooogle Play Service ( ex: GoogleApiClient) to get full address from lat /lng Or get placeId from lat/lng.

I mean, what is Android Api class for 
[Reverse Geocoding for a Latitude/Longitude](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#reverse-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try with googleapis.com, geocode get location from lat an lng

simply try to pass your lat and long to the following query string, and you will get a json array, fetch your city from there

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=10.792986,106.670004&sensor=true

Comment: It's awesome ! But I wonder if currently Google Play Service support a class to do that?